# How can I use “do while” in mocha testing

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

For example, I have:

```
function test1() {
  it("Test 1", function (done) {
    ...
  });
}

function test2() {
  it("Test 2", function (done) {
    ...
  });
}

describe("main()", function () {
  do {
    test1();
    test2();
  } while (resultReturnBool);
});
```

Although resultReturnBool is "true", it does not redo test1 and test2.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using do-while correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The do...while seems correct, maybe because of the way Mocha works it doesn't accept doing this kind of thing, have you seen any test using do...while? (just a question, i'm new to testing and i'm learning jest).

Try doing a normal while.

```
while(resultReturnBool) {
   it('Test1', () => {
        // Yout test here
});
   it('Test2', () => {
        // Yout test here
});
}
```